# Python Json.loads format

Tags: python, json

This might seem stupid to you but I noticed something and I just dont udnerstand it.

```
h = '[{"b": [2, 4], "c": 3.0, "a": "A"}]'
json.loads(h)
```

This will work, but this:

```
h = '"[{"b": [2, 4], "c": 3.0, "a": "A"}]"'
json.loads(h)
```

Will raise an exepction
JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 5 (char 4)

```
h = '"hey"'
json.loads(h)
```

This will also work.

Can someone please explain to me the differences between ''','" and '?

Answer (score 1):

Consider the middle example, from the perspective of individual strings (within your strin), you are asking json to load. By adding the first `"`, you are shifing all strings by one:

```
h = '"[{"b": [2, 4], "c": 3.0, "a": "A"}]"'
      --   ----------   -------   --
Strings surrounded by quotes
```

So when you first reach a non string `b`, json has no idea what to do with it. If you want to treat the entire content as a string, you need to escape the quotes `\\"`. So it would look like this:

```
h = '"[{\\"b\\": [2, 4], \\"c\\": 3.0, \\"a\\": \\"A\\"}]"'
```

Comment: What about ''' ? Some things wont work with ' " or just '

Comment: `'` and `"` can be used interchangably. The only difference is, when you use one, you can include the other without having to escape it `"\""` is equivalent to `'"'`

Answer (score 0):

It's saying that the character number 4 is not recognized.

That's normal, the decoder goes like that

```
char 0 " --> this is a string start
char 1 [ --> this is inside the string
char 2 { --> this is inside the string
char 3 " --> this is the end of the string
char 4 b --> this has nothing to do here, stop execution and raise error
```

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
h = '"[{"b": [2, 4], "c": 3.0, "a": "A"}]"'
```

you are attempting to use `"` for 2 different meanings: as string delimiter (1st and last) and literal `"` (all others). In such case way of escaping is required to tell *that `"` is literally `"`* consider what would be effect of following dumps

```
import json
text = 'this text does contain "quotation" marks'
print(json.dumps(text))
```

gives output

```
"this text does contain \"quotation\" marks"
```

Note `\` pointing *literal* `"`.